# Spring jpa repository returns the entity class instead of the dto interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data jpa in the backend codes. I have included entities, dto interfaces, service and jpa repository codes.

Now the issue is that when I call `getAllTopics()` in the `TopicService`. It returns a list of `Topic` object instead of `TopicDto`. `Topic` object includes a list of `examples` which I do not include in the `TopicDto`. And `Topic` object also includes a list of `Comment` object instead of `CommentDto`.

This only happens when I add `Set<CommentDto> getComments()` in `TopicDto`. If I remove it, everything work fine. Can anyone tell me how should I map the dto in my service and repository class? Why does it return entity class instead of dto?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TOPIC")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            mappedBy = "topic"
        )
    private Set<Comment> comments= new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            mappedBy = "topic"
        )
    private Set<Example> examples = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENT")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Comment implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Topic_ID")
    private Topic topic;

    @OneToMany(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,
            mappedBy = "comment"
        )
    private Set<AnotherExample> anotherExamples = new HashSet<>();  
}
```

```
public interface TopicDto{
    Long getId();
    Set<CommentDto> getComments();
}
```

```
public interface CommentDto{
    Long getId();
}
```

```
public interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<Topic, Long> {   
    List<TopicDto> findAllBy(Sort sort);
}
```

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TopicService {
   private final TopicRepository topicRepository ;

   public TopicService(TopicRepository topicRepository ) {
      this.topicRepository = topicRepository ;
   }

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<TopicDto> getAllTopics(Sort sort) {
      List<TopicDto> l = topicRepository.findAllBy(sort);
      return l;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Since you are saying that it actually works when you remove `Set<CommentDto> getComments()` from `TopicDto`, what are you using to trigger the mapping from `Topic` to `TopicDto`?

Comment: @JoãoDias, I thought it will be mapped automatically. Do I miss any config? Thanks

Comment: There is no automatic mapping unless you are willing to use other libraries on top of Spring: [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/). I usually avoid using such magic mappers and prefer to do it on my own, but this is definitely a personal preference.

Comment: @JoãoDias. Thanks for your quick answer. Would you mind showing me an example how to do a mapping from ```Topic``` to ```TopicDto``` by your own instead of using the libraries? That would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I will add an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187532/how-to-declare-repositories-based-on-entity-interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to change your `TopicRepository` to use `Topic`, the actual entity, and not `TopicDto`:

```java
public interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<Topic, Long> {   
    List<Topic> findAllBy(Sort sort);
}
```

Then, you need the following DTO classes:

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TopicDto {
    private Long id;
    private Set<CommentDto> comments= new HashSet<>();

    public TopicDto(Long id, Set<CommentDto> comments) {
        this.id = id;
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

```java
public class CommentDto {
    private Long id;

    public CommentDto(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `TopicService` you need to do the mapping from `Topic` to `TopicDto` as follows:

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class TopicService {
   private final TopicRepository topicRepository ;

   public TopicService(TopicRepository topicRepository ) {
      this.topicRepository = topicRepository ;
   }

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<TopicDto> getAllTopics(Sort sort) {
      List<Topic> topics = topicRepository.findAllBy(sort);
      return topics.stream()
                .map(topic -> {
                    Set<CommentDto> commentsDto = topic.getComments().stream()
                            .map(comment -> new CommentDto(comment.getId()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                    return new TopicDto(topic.getId(), commentsDto);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

– the domain type the repository manages
 – the type of the id of the entity the repository manages

so that is normal to return domain object. You specified @Entity the Topic Class.

I hope the answer was helpful.